# Perl - OOP/Moose - method signatures

Tags: performance, perl, oop, moose, method-signature

I like to code OO in Perl like this:

```
use MooseX::Declare;
use Method::Signatures::Modifiers;
use v5.14.2;


class Talker
{
     method talk (Str $text) {
         $self=>say $text;

     }

     my $talk_object = Talker->new();
     $talk_object->talk('Hello!');
}
```

Unfortunately this is quite slow, I couldn't find any Mouse or Moo equivalent to it. 
What a pity that Perl hasn't got anything like PyPy.

Does someone know how to archive the same with the lighter implementations?

Comment: What about it is slow exactly? If you're talking about the compile-time impacts of using Moose, it might be better to avoid repeated compilation by using some sort of persistent code.

Comment: Yes, it is compile time. At least, as far as I can see now. Trying to avoid repeated compilation is not a nice hack here...:/. Will have a look at Moops. OOP still has somehow a bad taste in Perl unfortunately because of these jumble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The experimental [`Moops`](https://metacpan.org/module/Moops) module is another syntax extension that works fairly similar. It is inspired by MooseX::Declare (but is faster) and by the p5-mop project that is trying to bring such syntax into core perl.

Your example would translate without significant changes. If you want to specify a MOP backend, you can declare a class like `class Foo using Moose`, but it defaults to `Moo`, which is simpler than Moose.

Comment: It's definitely worth looking at Moops. Seems to get a reasonable balance between weight and convenience for me - just started trying it in some small cron-driven scripts. Startup time seems OK to me. Does require a recent (5.14+) version of Perl though.